# How to use PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP

Tags: android, wakelock, powermanager

How can I  use `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP`? `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` must be used with another wakelock or you risk an error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify a valid wake lock level.
```

However, `FULL_WAKE_LOCK`, `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`, and `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` are all deprecated, and `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` doesn't work with `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`

> "Cannot be used with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK."

[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP)

So does that mean that `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` is effectively useless?

Answer (score -4):

You can use it like this:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock screenWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                TAG);
```

Comment: docs explicitly say `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` can't be used with `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`